# is it possible to hide the Input field in the Primeng Calendar?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

Is it possible to hide the `input` field in the primeng calendar, and show only the icon? I don't want to change the `p-calendar` element to inline, but just display the icon that will pop up the calendar.

component.html

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
  <p-calendar class="foo-cal" appendTo="body" readonlyInput="true" dateFormat="yy/mm/dd" [(ngModel)]="date" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

I tried the following, but no success:

```
body .ui-calendar.ui-calendar-w-btn .ui-inputtext {
    display: none !important;
}

p-calendar span input {
    display: none !important;
}
```

However, with the devtools in the browser if I add the `display: none;` property to the element, it will hide leaving the icon only. Any ideas how can I make this to render the html file without the input field?

Comment: Check th Style part for the casses of component  ex. the ui-inputtext class, you can override the casses on the global style file of angular

Comment: thanks, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi @chris if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 

Comment: hi @malbarmawi! I just accepted your answer, thanks for the solution ;) I ended up using another lib for the calendar, but I tried implementing your solution to double check it worked in my project too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a custom style for the p-calendar component

```html
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
  <h3>Icon</h3>
  <p-calendar styleClass="only-icon" [(ngModel)]="date" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

style.scss

```css
.only-icon {
 .ui-inputtext{
   display: none;
 }
 button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-calendar-button  {
   border-radius: 4px !important;
 }
}
```

[**demo ⚡⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-oumx4s)

apply this style to all componnt without any custome class

```css
p-calendar {
 .ui-inputtext{
   display: none;
 }
 button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-calendar-button  {
   border-radius: 4px !important;
 }
}
```

> the style above gone to apply to a `p-calendar` to all  project.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set display none for input , users can't see calendar when click in there but you can use this css code for input and show your icon as image in background-image.

```css
input{
    border: none;
    background-image: url(your-icon-address);
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    /*width:somthing; if you need*/
    /*height:somthing; if you need*/
}
input:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```

you can set width and height input same as icon.

Comment: This!! Thank you!! 
The accepted answer didn't work for me, so I did this solution but modified it a bit: 
:host ::ng-deep .p-inputtext {
  border: none;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 0 !important;
  heigt: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

Comment: Also replace "outline: 0" with "box-shadow: none !important;", because box-shadow is the property that causes the outline on the onFocus for all PrimeNG elements

Answer (score 0):

For me "hiding" the input element with css did the job:

`p-calendar > span > input { display: none; }`